# Returning value of local variable. Which one is bad practice?

Tags: c, return-value, scope

My code is as below

```
main(){
  int *a;
  a = fun1():
  printf("%d",&a);
}
```

My fun1 is

```
int* fun1(){
  int a = 10;
  return &a;
}
```

The other version of the same is

```
int* fun1(){
  int* a = malloc(sizeof(int));
  *a = 10;
  return a;
}
```

Now, I am guessing in the first one, when I do `int a = 10` in the function, then it will create a local variable a. And if I try to pass the address of that variable outside of the function, it will go out of scope, and hence when I reference it again from main, I'll get garbage value.

But in the second, since the pointer is the local variable, when I return it, I get a copy of the address, but since I have the address now, (even though in a different location to where it was inside the fun1()), I can reference it from main.

Is it right? Am I right in my understanding?

Also, if instead of return pointer to int, I was returning int.

```
int fun(){
  int a = 10;
  return a;
}
```

and in main function, I just print the value of this return value, even then it will work right?

Thanks

Comment: The first one is not just bad practice, it's incorrect and undefined behaviour.

Comment: The first one is wrong. I believe the second is fine, but I would suggest using something more like the third.

Comment: The first one is wrong, you are returning a reference to a local variable. In the second one you return a copy of the local int* varaible a. Between 2 and 3, depends on what you want to return. An int* or an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one is bad practice and leads to all sort of problems.

Second one has the problem if the user of the function forgets to free the pointer.

Third one is the best option as does not have either problem.

If you need to pass back a larger data structure pass a pointer to it as a argument and get the function to fill it in.